# ruby page on Heroku comes up with error: 'we're sorry but something went wrong'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Hi in the last week pushed a ROR rake task to prod and then ran the rake task to update some table fields in heroku.
Everything was seemed fine at the time but this week I did something that I hadn't done in the previous week of creating a new practice or editing one gives an error of  'we're sorry but something went wrong'
The error message I get from running --tail in the terminal says

```
Completed 500 internal server error in 34ms
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'practices' for nil:NilClass);
```

This is my production application.
In the staging application I don't get this error.

The 2 environments are supposed to be the same.
Is a migration needed? or failing that how could I work out what is going wrong.

thanks
maggs

Comment: did you rake db:migrate, there is a an object that is returning nil that you are calling `practices` on

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and try

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Hi I have run the migrate command heroku run rake db:migrate and still get the same error. thanks maggs

Comment: Yes I got the same error when clicking on the new or edit button

Answer (score 0):

**Database**

> The 2 environments are supposed to be the same. Is a migration needed?

It depends on if you're using the same database in production & development

By default, Heroku gives you a blank [PGSQL database](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), or you can override their `DATABASE_URL` config variable to [use your own db](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

> heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=mysql://your_database

---

**Recommendation**

For now, I would recommend performing a `heroku run rake db:migrate` on your Heroku database, as this will provide the right data structure for your app

The real problem, though, is you're calling `practices` on an undefined object (`nil:class`). To ensure this is not a problem, you either need some logic such as:

```
unless @variable.nil?
   # do something
end
```

or you need to ensure you're working with the correct data

Comment: Hi I am using the same database in production & development thanks maggs